# How to access wamp server via host file from windows 8 to windows xp?

Tags: php, wamp

I Installed wamp server(v2.1) on my windows 8 pc. Now i need to access those files, which i already created virtual domain name, in another pc which runs on windows xp.

i tried usual method of editing host file in XP with the ip and domain name but it doesnt works.

Pls help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not enough information. What error do you get on the XP machine? It is not found, is it permission denied, something else? Show us what you have tried in your hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the hosts file on the Windows 8 PC. A machine's hosts file is used only by the machine itself for domain lookups.